# file permission in windows 7 chmod

Tags: php, joomla, chmod

i created a sub-folder under `images` folder in joomla. when i try to access the `images` folder through browser, i don't see anything but if i try to access the sub-folder as `http://localhost/joomla/images/downloads` then the directory listing is shown or the files are visible.

now i wanna know how i can hide the files in the sub-folders too. i know how it is done via ftp software but don't know how to do it in windows 7. something like chmod in linux

Comment: put an empty index.html file in the folder. But the "right" solution would be to disable directory indexes for subfolders at server level (nothing related to chmod, though)

Comment: I think the directory setting Damien is referring to is located in the IIS settings on your Windows Server. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla has blank *index.html* files in all its' directories to that if someone tried to access a specific folder, they would see a blank screen, instead of a file tree. So create a blank *index.html* file and upload it to the folder you wish to hide the file names from